# Hibernate updating child entries in one to many Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a

1. company table
2. department table
3. employee table.

I am using hibernate to persist data in the database.

**1. One to Many Relationship between Company and Department .**

A company can have multiple departments and a department can have multiple employees.

I have done corresponding one to many mapping of entities as mentioned in below code. Request to update these entities comes from UI in the JSON format.

I have provided company Id, department Id, and employee Id in the request. 
Now Suppose If for a particular company , there is one department in the database  with dept_id 3 . . In the Json request, I get a request to update that particular company with one more department. So after updation, previous entry should remain as it is, i.e department with ID 3 ,should remain untouched and new entry should be added with some department Id, say 4,.

Now that company would have two departments one with Id 3 and other with id 4.

How could this be achieved??..Also department entries , which are not there in the request, should be deleted from the database... Same goes for the relation between employee and department,.request may ask to add new employee for a particular department,keeping the existing one.

Please help me with this, what configuration/approach has to be done in my code, to achieve this.
Here is the code for these three tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private long companyId;

    @Column(name = "company_region")
    private String companayRegion;

    @Column(name = "company_code")
    private String companyCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<department> departments;


    public Company() {
    }
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "dept_id")
    private long departmentID;

    @Column(name = "dep_code")
    private String departmentCode;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "emp_code")
    private String empCode;

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String empname;

    @Column(name = "employee_city")
    private String employeeCity;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    private Department department;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your JSON contains companyId / departmentID / employeeId
2. Load the company by companyId
3. INSERT all department entries where `departmentID == 0`, and fetch the generated ID (Hibernate will update the POJO, or return a new one with the ID set)
4. UPDATE all department entries where `departmentID > 0`, and remember the used departmentID
5. Iterate over `company.getDepartments()` and `iterator.remove()` entries with departmentID not contained in the collection built from (3) and (4)
6. By persisting the `company` Hibernate will detect which departments were removed, and delete those

Do basically the same for the department -> employee relationship

Answer (score 0):

the mappings seem correct, what you need is to use `merge` to obtain an Hibernate-managed entity and copy the fields from the detached instance (coming from the REST api):

```
Company c = (Company) session.merge(companyFromDto);
```

Merge should take care to create a new Company, or update an existing one (depending if it is already in the DB) as well as cascade the associations.

Comment: I am using @transactional and getting the company ID with in this transaction. And i update this object under transaction, rather than calling session.update() method. I used cascade. Merge, but it didn't work.